# Web API in ASP.net C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webapi

I want to create a web API controller that returns product details with id. Using stored procedure calls from a database class, not DB context. Sending Request with ID & getting a response with Jason's values.
I saw many examples but they are directly using stored procedures from the DB context. But I want to introduce a connection string & call that method in business class than a business class call to the controller with the response return.

Please help with a small example

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example. You can choose between using SQL Command or SQL Adapter, try searching a little bit more about it.

**Programming isn't only writing a code it's also googling for solutions.**

```
// Setup connection string to access local SQL Server 2000

    string connectionString = "server=localhost;" +
    "database=Northwind;uid=sa;pwd=manager";

    // Instantiate the connection, passing the
    // connection string into the constructor
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    // Open the connection
    con.Open();

    // Create and execute the query
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers",con);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Iterate through the DataReader and display row
    while(reader.Read()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",
        reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
    }
```

[Source](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_dbaccess.html)

Comment: I am looking for a data layer class where I can define my stored procedure, then I will call that procedure in business class, the Business class then can be called in the controller with request class & return Jason response. Please help in building the whole API with these steps

Comment: @Zeldalink hi, welcome to SO, you might like to review the help pages, specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - your "question" (actually a general request for someone to do you work for you) is way too broad.  Please limit to a specific request that you are having difficulty with.  Your "build whole API" requirement can likely be covered by any number of online tutorials on how to create a multi-tier app / data layer.